# Why Fix Button in Bottom in Coordinator Layout scroll with recycle view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

i want to have a recycle view and a fix button in bottom of that.
i use coordinator layout and everything is ok but when scroll of recycle view ended, the fix button move a little with recycle view.
what is the problem??

This is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/filter_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shopsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/complete_info_order"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/complete_info_order"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_frame"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

what should i do to button don't move with recycle view??

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shopsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/complete_info_order"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but i want that button be on the recycle view items but in bottom of that..that means i want that recycle view be in behind of button..because of that i use coordinatelayout

Comment: You want the Button overlapping the RecyclerView? OK, see my edit above. CoordinatorLayouts are really for coordinating movements between Views, and that's not what you want here.